# Save HEX data to file

Tags: c#, file-io, hex

I'm having some problems saving the edited data to the original file...
I want to save my string from textBox1 to the file it was loaded from.

Here is my "Load" function:

```
public static string getItemName(int index)
{
    FileStream str = File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ybi);
    BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(str);
    breader.BaseStream.Position = itemSectionStart;
    byte[] itemSection = breader.ReadBytes(itemSectionEnd);

    string itemName = BitConverter.ToString(itemSection, 808 * index + 7, 64).Replace("00", "").Replace("-", "");
    return hex2ascii(itemName);

}
```

Here is my "Save" function:

```
public static bool setItemName(int index, string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 808 * index + 7, _ByteArray.Length);
        _FileStream.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception _Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(_Exception.Message));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, I think here is where the problem is, in the conversion from my HEX String to ByteArray...

```
private byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    int hexStringLength = hexString.Length;
    byte[] b = new byte[hexStringLength / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hexStringLength; i += 2)
    {
        int topChar = (hexString[i] > 0x40 ? hexString[i] - 0x37 : hexString[i] - 0x30) << 4;
        int bottomChar = hexString[i + 1] > 0x40 ? hexString[i + 1] - 0x37 : hexString[i + 1] - 0x30;
        b[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(topChar + bottomChar);
    }
    return b;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in textBox1.Text)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    writeValuePositions.setItemName(index, save_FileName, HexStringToByteArray(hex.ToUpper()));
}
```

The byteArray that gets sent to writeValuePositions.setItemName isnt right I think... I get this Exception

```
---------------------------

---------------------------
Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: Please do not prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: A couple of notes that are not answers: 1) Your streams and BinaryReader should be in `using` blocks to ensure they are disposed of promptly when you're done with them, even if an exception is thrown. 2) Don't use `Convert.ToString(_Exception.Message))`. `Message` is already a string. Also you'd do better to use `_Exception.ToString()` which will display the complete exception.

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential issue with your line in setItemName:

`_FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 808 * index + 7, _ByteArray.Length);`

The second parameter is starting offset, and the third parameter is the total count of character to be written.  Looks like you are writing 808 * index + 7 bytes passed the end of your array.  If you want to write out to the end of your array, subtract the offset from the count.

Comment: First parameter: array containing data to write
Second parameter: offset indicating where to begin to copy the bytes
Third parameter: Lenght of array

the offset parameter is where the "item name" is stored and where it will be saved, I don't see how I am going beyond the end

Comment: The third parameter is NOT supposed to be the total length of the array.  It is supposed to be the number of bytes to read from the array.  Assuming `array` was a single byte per character representation of "hello world" and you wanted to write "world", your call parameters would be `stream.Write(array, 6, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    writeValuePositions.setItemName(index, save_FileName, HexStringToByteArray(textBox1.Text);
}

private byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hexString) || hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
   {
      throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter.");
   }

   byte[] array = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];

   for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length / 2; i++)
   {
      array[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
   }
   return array;
}
```

Bear in mind what John Saunders has suggested you in his comment though.